# How to remove coupling without duplicating the code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, game-engine

I'm making a server for a multiplayer game and have some problems figuring out how to make the logic modular. When a player move I want to update the object, update the database record and emit the move to all connected clients. Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
var socket = require('./socket');
var db = require('./db');

function Player(id, x, y) {
    this.id = id;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

Player.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    db.update({id: this.id}, {x: x, y: y});
    socket.emit('player moved', {x: x, y: y});
}
```

This tightly couples the socket and database to the player object which feels wrong. However, I don't want to do db.update and socket.emit in the game loop every time I update the player object.

What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this question is fit for SO, please correct me if I get it wrong on that point. However, here's how I would go: To slightly decouple your player from the DB/Socket, use an abstraction layer. Your `move` function calls this abstraction layer, the other objects (sockets and databases for example) subscribe callbacks to be executed. It could look like an event layer, or a pub/sub pattern.

Comment: First off, this is entirely too opinion-based for StackOverflow -- unless it's a syntax question (which this isn't), "proper" is subjective. Second off, you should really validate the new x/y against the old one to make sure no one is hacking, or I could pretty easily teleport wherever by saying "move {x: 1000, y;1000}". Third off, _why_ does it feel wrong? Is there any particular reason you _need_ to decouple your player from your socket and DB? If you can answer that, you'll be a lot closer to figuring out how to decouple it so it feels better.

Comment: Thanks and I'm sorry if this is not a good fit for SO. Is there a Stack Exchange for these type of questions? Regarding validating move is never called by a player directly. This happens on the server, not in the browser. All input that is sent from the client is "pressed left button".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do two things:

1) have your Player class emit events. This lets you add more triggers in the future without having to modify your Player class

2) Use a pos object to hold your x and y values. This makes the code more concise.

```
// In Player file
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

function Player(id, pos) {
  this.id = id;
  this.pos = pos;
}

Player.events = new EventEmitter();

Player.prototype.move = function (pos) {
  Player.events.emit('move', this);
};

module.exports = Player;

// In database file...
var db = require('./db');
var Player = require('./Player');

Player.events.on('move', function (player) {
  db.update({id: player.id}, player.pos);
});

// In socket file...
var socket = require('./socket');
var Player = require('./Player');

Player.events.on('move', function (player) {
  socket.emit('player moved', player.pos);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Any reason not to put events on the prototype and calling it with this?

Comment: You could do that but you'd have to attach listeners to all your instantiated Player objects. For example `var bob = new Player(); bob.on('move',fn);`. You could do that in Player constructor but that means you would have to modify your constructor every time you want to add a new listener.

Answer (score 2):

If the only purpose of the `Player` "class" is to handle these sorts of updates, then the only real change I see making is to parameterize the player code rather than having it directly include the db and socket. But it's a very small change, as the require calls already make somewhat decoupled.

I can see three ways to do that:

1. Make them arguments to `Player`:

   ```
   function Player(id, x, y, db, socket) {
       this.id = id;
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
       this.db = db;
       this.socket = socket;
   }

   Player.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;

       this.db.update({id: this.id}, {x: x, y: y});
       this.socket.emit('player moved', {x: x, y: y});
   };
   ```

But you end up with those references in every object.

2. Make them arguments to a builder function that creates the `Player` constructor

   ```
   exports.buildPlayerClass = function(db, socket) {

       function Player(id, x, y) {
           this.id = id;
           this.x = x;
           this.y = y;
       }

       Player.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
           this.x = x;
           this.y = y;

           db.update({id: this.id}, {x: x, y: y});
           socket.emit('player moved', {x: x, y: y});
       };
   };
   ```

   Usage in the calling module is then:

   ```
   var socket = require('./socket');
   var db = require('./db');
   var Player = require('./player').buildPlayerClass(db, socket);

   // ...

   var p = new Player("some-id", 0, 0);
   ```
3. Make `Player` an `EventEmitter` that emits `move` events:

   ```
   var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

   function Player(id, x, y) {
       EventEmitter.call(this);
       this.id = id;
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
   }
   Player.prototype = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype);
   Player.prototype.constructor = Player;

   Player.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;

       this.emit('move', {p: this, x: x, y: y});
   };
   ```

   Usage is then:

   ```
   var socket = require('./socket');
   var db = require('./db');

   // ...

   var p = new Player("some-id", 0, 0);
   p.on('move', function(e) {
       db.update({id: e.p.id}, {x: e.x, y: e.y});
       socket.emit('player moved', {x: e.x, y: e.y});
   });
   ```
4. Make `Player` use a **common** event emitter:

   ```
   function Player(id, x, y, emitter) {
       this.id = id;
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
       this.emitter = emitter;
   }

   Player.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;

       this.emitter.emit('move', {p: this, x: x, y: y});
   };
   ```

   Usage is then:

   ```
   var playerEvents = new EventEmitter();
   playerEvents.on('move', function(e) {
       db.update({id: e.p.id}, {x: e.x, y: e.y});
       socket.emit('player moved', {x: e.x, y: e.y});
   });

   // ...

   var p1 = new Player("p1", 0, 0, playerEvents);
   var p2 = new Player("p2", 0, 0, playerEvents);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I myself am very interested in seeing suggestions for decoupling in this situation. My personal suggestion

```
Player.prototype.observers = [];
Player.prototype.observers.push(
      function(){
          if(conditionToUpdateDb){
              db.update({id: this.id}, {x: this.x, y: this.y});
          }
      });
Player.prototype.observers.push(
      function(){
          if(conditionToEmit){
              socket.emit('player moved', {x: this.x, y: this.y});
          }
      });
```

and then

```
Player.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    for(key in this.observers){
        this.observers[key]();
    }
}
```

If you want different `observers` for different `Players`, you can alternatively do

```
function Player(id, x, y, observers) {
    this.id = id;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.observers = observers;
}
```

and then

```
for(key in this.observers){
        this.observers[key]();
    }
```